# How can i read special characters from a URL parameter as characters and not as ASCII code

Tags: typescript, parameters, angular6, angular-activatedroute

I have these asp.net reset password generated code in the url:

```
Code=xC4f1pHtzHdc2NtBTHpWeNzfY%2FIoPDbPvg1AeKA7COHifBOIGcxTeboaI6BtkQsuabs6CS7TGcdUxGy1pDUMmcLMnxVfaC1Jnxjz7O7PZetsU%20XDVZWkdMD0EenBchsZR%2FTUlufM36ULD%2FdH3WVXR9tZA1lUhPPQG2M4kb4Nrg3YZUmDZVDrKbXeBaktKXIwEItmYLwGmg%2FUm8Rn4%2FULrg%3D%3D
```

i need to reed it as it is i have written this code:

```
  Code: string;
  constructor(
     private acitivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  )
  this.Code = params ['Code'];
```

my problem is that it is reading some characters as ASCII so after loging it in my console this is what i get

xC4f1pHtzHdc2NtBTHpWeNzfY/IoPDbPvg1AeKA7COHifBOIGcxTeboaI6BtkQsuabs6CS7TGcdUxGy1pDUMmcLMnxVfaC1Jnxjz7O7PZetsU XDVZWkdMD0EenBchsZR/TUlufM36ULD/dH3WVXR9tZA1lUhPPQG2M4kb4Nrg3YZUmDZVDrKbXeBaktKXIwEItmYLwGmg/Um8Rn4/ULrg==

my probleme is that i want to read th special characters as they are

Comment: Do you mean, for example,  `/` becomes `%2F` and your code is receiving it as %2f when you want a / ?

Comment: @CaiusJard actually the opposite is happening %2f becomes / and i want it %2f